# pass file or filename to function

Tags: c++, python, coding-style

In a programming language that has a file object, would you rather pass this object to a function or the path to the physical file and let the function open the file itself?

If the language does matter for your answer, please consider c++ and python.

Thanks,

Somebody

Comment: In python, it's not so hard to create a function which will allow you to pass either ...

Comment: @KonradRudolph -- good to know.  I assumed something like that should be possible, but I didn't know with the strong typing and everything.  (I know C pretty well, but I never really got interested in C++).

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of good coding practices is to open the file where the information is to be used and not in a more global scope in any language.

Comment: I don’t think OP was talking about open files.

Comment: I think that it depends a little bit on type of file.  For example, if it is a large (unstructured) ascii file and you want to read a part near the end, you need to read everything in the beginning to get where you want to go which can be a performance issue.

Answer (score 2):

I’m all for strong typing so passing a file path object around as much as possible makes sense. Boost provides the [`boost::filesystem::path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) class for this purpose.

However, this should be hassle-free. For instance, there is probably little harm in providing an implicit conversion from `string` to `fileobject` (but not the other way round!) so functions accepting the former would also accept the path as a bare string (and do the right thing with it).

Likewise, some functions in Python expect an opened file object, but if you pass an instance of `str` to it they will just construct such an object by calling `open(path, 'r')` themselves.

However, note that I distinguish here between

- an object representing the file input/output stream – `ifstream` / `ofstream` in C++, `file` in Python (**do *not* pass this around**), and
- an object representing the *path* of the file in the file system, e.g. `boost::filesystem::path` – ***do* pass this around**.

For comparison, .NET has the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class for the purpose of representing a file system object, while it uses the [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) class to represent a … well, file *stream*.

Comment: What is the difference between an "object representing the actual file" and the "opened file object" expected by Python?  Could you clarify that point a bit?

Comment: @mgilson It’s the difference between a [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) and  a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx). The latter corresponds to the Python type [`file`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file) – the former has no correspondence.

Comment: I assumed that's what you were talking about (though I didn't know the actual c++ terms).  I just didn't think it came through particularly clear in your post.  It's better now.  (+1)

Comment: @mgilson See update, I incorporated the links there, and added a link to a C++ implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

That depends very much on the specific case.

If I were to use the file in several (sub)functions than I would rather pass the initialised file object (or function).

If I have one function to get the filename and path and another to do something with the data of the file, I would probably prefer to pass the path and filename and have the file opened by the function that uses the data.

Comment: See above; I don’t think OP was talking about a file *stream* object.